# How to avoid ambiguous as using full outer join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables that need to be joined.

Multiple column such as "P_SERIAL_ID", "CONTACT_NOTE"...etc would be ambiguous if I use below query.

"P_SERIAL_ID" and "CONTACT_NOTE" are columns belong to "B_COLLECTION"."COLLECTION_CONSENT_RC" and "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RC".
"B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" doesn't have those two columns.

How to solve this issue?

```
SELECT "P_SERIAL_ID","CONTACT_NOTE" 
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" AS DAT
    FULL OUTER JOIN "B_COLLECTION"."COLLECTION_CONSENT_RC" AS SUBID ON DAT."P_SERIAL_ID" = SUBID."SUBJECT_ID"
    FULL OUTER JOIN "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RC" AS TR ON TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = DAT."P_SERIAL_ID"
  WHERE DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9')
) AS SHIT0 
WHERE "SUBJECT_CITIZEN_ID" IS NOT NULL;
```

I want this query achieve this without ambiguous. shit0 fulfill the condition and contain all three tables without ambiguous.
[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  In any query, you should qualify *all* column names.  That will fix your particular problem.

Comment: could you provide solution to avoid "P_SERIAL_ID","CONTACT_NOTE" being ambijuous?

Comment: into which table `CONTACT_NOTE` and `SUBJECT_CITIZEN_ID` belongs?

Comment: The solution is to **not** use `select *` but to list only those columns you actually need. *Especially* if you only need two of them in the outer select

Comment: **Always fully qualify all your selected columns with `table_name_or_alias.column_name`**. You've no idea when someone will add a same-name column in future, and cause a sudden ambiguity in a was-working-before query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully qualify all your columns, even consider renaming them so they're unique:

```
SELECT dat_serial_id, tr_serial_id, dat_contact_note, tr_contact_note
FROM (
  SELECT 

    "DAT"."P_SERIAL_ID" as dat_serial_id,
    "TR"."P_SERIAL_ID" as tr_serial_id,
    "DAT"."CONTACT_NOTE" as dat_contact_note,
    "TR"."CONTACT_NOTE" as tr_contact_note,
    "SUBID"."SUBJECT_CITIZEN_ID" --guessed at the table


  FROM "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" AS DAT
    FULL OUTER JOIN "B_COLLECTION"."COLLECTION_CONSENT_RC" AS SUBID ON DAT."P_SERIAL_ID" = SUBID."SUBJECT_ID"
    FULL OUTER JOIN "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RC" AS TR ON TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = DAT."P_SERIAL_ID"
  WHERE DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9')
) AS SHIT0 
WHERE shit0."SUBJECT_CITIZEN_ID" IS NOT NULL;
```

Rename them as early as possible, to avoid pitfalls and confusion in using the wrong one. If you don't need all the different serial_no etc, then so long as you're specific about which one you want in the inner query, you can carry on referring to it by the same name in the outer query

The problem largely comes because of the `SELECT *` - avoid using it on anything other than top level queries, for debugging

Using a WHERE clause that targets any table that is full joined reduces the join to a left/right join. If the table you've WHERE'd is on the right/left side of a left/right join respectively drops that to an inner join:

```
--same as a left join b
SELECT * FROM a FULL JOIN B ON … WHERE a.id = 1

--same as a right join b
SELECT * FROM a FULL JOIN B ON … WHERE b.id = 1

--same as a inner join b
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN B ON … WHERE a.id = 1
SELECT * FROM a RIGHT JOIN B ON … WHERE b.id = 1
```

Comment: b and a got id column both.
However, b.id doesn't mean the same as a.id. a.id would not equal to b.id forever. 
where condition is a must.
how to make this a full join?

Comment: Whatever you're considering putting on the where clause, put in the ON clause instead. `A LEFT JOIN B ON (...) WHERE b.col ='test'` is inner join because LEFT join adds nulls for B rows that don't match, but `WHERE b.col = 'test'` is always false for the rows where b.col is null, so the where clause removes all the rows the left join added.. putting in the ON clause e.g `A LEFT JOIN B ON (...) AND b.col ='test'` Keeps the outer join working as outer join

Answer (score 0):

You are using * in derived table and referring to columns so check this

```
SELECT "P_SERIAL_ID" 
FROM (
  SELECT TR."P_SERIAL_ID"
  FROM "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" AS DAT
    FULL OUTER JOIN "B_COLLECTION"."COLLECTION_CONSENT_RC" AS SUBID ON DAT."P_SERIAL_ID" = SUBID."SUBJECT_ID"
    FULL OUTER JOIN "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RC" AS TR ON TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = DAT."P_SERIAL_ID"
  WHERE DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7','8','9')
) AS SHIT0 
WHERE "SUBJECT_CITIZEN_ID" IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `FULL JOIN` is rarely needed an not appropriate in this situation.

```
SELECT DAT."P_SERIAL_ID", ?."CONTACT_NOTE"    -- Add the table alias!
FROM "B_TRACE"."P_TC_DATA" DAT LEFT JOIN
     "B_COLLECTION"."COLLECTION_CONSENT_RC" SUBID
     ON DAT."P_SERIAL_ID" = SUBID."SUBJECT_ID" LEFT JOIN
     "B_TRACE"."P_TC_RC" TR
     ON TR."P_SERIAL_ID" = DAT."P_SERIAL_ID"
WHERE DAT."STATE_ID" IN ('7', '8', '9') AND  -- Are these really strings?
      ?."SUBJECT_CITIZEN_ID" IS NOT NULL;    -- Add the table alias!
```

Notes:

- No subquery is necessary.
- The `WHERE` clause turns the `FULL JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN` anyway.  `FULL JOIN` is almost never needed in a well defined data model.
- The `IN` list is strings in your example.  These are probably numbers, so you should drop the single quotes.
- Qualify *ALL* table names.  The above query has `?` as a placeholder for the table alias.
- Get rid of the double quotes in your query.  They only make it harder to write and to read.
- Depending on the table where `SUBJECT_CITIZEN_ID` comes from, all the `JOIN`s might really be `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: Does this query contain all columns in three table and exclude duplicate column?

Comment: @fink168 . . . No.  This query selects the same columns that your query does.

Comment: Got it. I think my query is wrong. I want the query contain all columns, fulfill the condition and exclude duplicate column.